# Is there a way to force a Mac laptop to stay in a specific resolution?

Tags: display, resolution

I sometimes open up my Macbook Pro and notice that my laptop panel is an odd resolution. When I check Display settings, it shows "Best for Display", when I really want the highest setting always.

Is there a utility or command that can be used to automatically set the display resolution automatically?

Comment: Have a look at: [Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Sierra.  Just paste the following script Into script editor.app

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1
    click radio button 5 of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Run this script in script editor.app and make sure it works for you.  If it works, just export it as an application and name it something like "Max Resolution.app" or what ever..

Now you want to enable this application to control your computer by adding it to the list of applications in System preferences/Accessibility/Security privacy. Like this..

[image]

Take it a step further by adding it to your login items if you want your computer to always start up with the max resolution.

[image]

Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Since you've opened System Preferences using `reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"`, it opens it to the Display tab, thus making `click radio button "Display" of tab group 1` unnecessary.

Comment: @user3439894 Nice catch! Thanks for the heads-up.  You are correct, I removed that line In the code and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

The [Display Menu app](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) (free with in-app purchases) can do this for you.